# Change Route after a function is done in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

so what i'm trying to do is I want to change `Route` after a function is done, for example i want user to enter his/her user name and password and if they were true redirect them to their profile, but i don't know how to do that and i don't want to do it using something like this

```
window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/dashboard"
```

so for example here's my code and i want to redirect it to Dashboard after the `api` call is done.

```
const handleSubmit = event => {
      event.preventDefault();

      const user = {
            phone_number: this.state.phone_number,
            password: this.state.password,
            gcm_id: 1,
            dev_type: "Web"
       };
       const headers = {
            'Authorization': "abc",
            'content-type': 'application/json'
       }
       localStorage.setItem('phone_number', this.state.phone_number);
       axios.post(`sth`, user, {
             headers: headers
       })
             .then(res => {
             localStorage.setItem('api_key', res.data.api_key)
             })
             .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
}
```

In here i want it to change Route after the `api_key' is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `this.props.history.push('/dashboard')` after the api key is set to route to the appropriate page.

Also add `withRouter` to the class export like  `export default withRouter(Register)`

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your class component with the `withRouter` HOC provided from `react-router`.

`import { withRouter } from "react-router";`

Then on success add this

```
.then(res => {
  localStorage.setItem('api_key', res.data.api_key);
  this.props.history.push('dashboard');
})
```

if you are using a function component:

```
import { useHistory} from "react-router-dom";

const history = useHistory();

.then(res => {
  localStorage.setItem('api_key', res.data.api_key);
  history.push('dashboard');
})
```